# Coding for Mathematics

Tags: programming, computer-arithmetic

I don't think this is the appropriate group to ask but since most of the people dealing with mathematics are involved, I prefer to ask here instead of the Stack Overflow site.

For my math works, it is good to resort to coding/programming. I don't mean being a game developer at this moment but learn coding, LaTeXing, web management and stuffs relating to works. Presently, I have a pretty basic knowledge of JAVA (and I use the awful BlueJ environment). Therefore, take me as a complete novice and help me from scratch. Refer me some good books, websites, softwares and stuffs that will help me with my works.

I think you all should better know what all to tell me because you people are involved in this matter. Am not stating any more; you people can help me a lot more than what I think I need help of.

Regards.

Comment: For math it's useful to know Python (with numpy). For a basic introduction to Python I recommend Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw,  although it is for general programmers and not math people. Zed Shaw has other good books too.

Comment: Okay, will begin with it. Yeah general programming is definitely better. Why learn only what's needed!? Anything can be needed. And any more answers/comments? Not about programming. What about LaTeX?

Comment: Latex is pretty easy. Personally I've found using TexnicCenter (wth the Sumatra PDF viewer) to be fairly painless. The websites detexify and tex.stackexchange are very useful.